# How to see what is new when I get a ubuntu touch update?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, release-management, phone

I'm working with my Ubuntu Touch BQ Aquaris phone for a month now but I can't seem to find out what the new features are when I get an update.
For instance, today I got an update to 14.10 (R21). Where could I find info on what changed in this version?

Answer (score 0):

You can always find information about a new version of Ubuntu in the [Release Notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UtopicUnicorn/ReleaseNotes#New_features_in_14.10).

Comment: Yes, I found those but there is nothing specific about Ubuntu touch, let alone the version update

Comment: If there are no specific notes about Ubuntu touch, then there were no major changes. A new version of Ubuntu comes out every 6 months (the 14 corresponds to the year, the 10 to the month). The new version would come out whether or not there were Ubuntu touch updates.

Answer (score 0):

The changelog is here:
http://people.canonical.com/~ogra/touch-image-stats/
Though this is created by a script and is only interesting if you know what you are searching (hoping) for.

I have not found yet the release notes for ubuntu touch.

Update:
I finally found the list of updates: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/04/16/phone-updates-april/
Under this link all updates from the OTA update as well for Telegram are listed.